# Tela me retorna o erro index was outside-the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

Tenho uma tela que salva os usuários, e atribui valor a eles, porém sempre quando clico no botão salvar ele me retorna o erro index was outside-the bounds of the array , eu ja vasculhei linhas e não consegui encontrar nada.

```
string[] commandParam = processParam.Split(new string[] { GV.stSep }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] field = commandParam[0].Split(new string[] { GV.stSep2 }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] value = commandParam[1].Split(new string[] { GV.stSep2 }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Acima é onde se encontra  o erro no C#,

Abaixo onde se encontra o possível erro no Javascript

```
var wrData = null;

        scr.getGrid("GWOReprogram").clear();

        if (cbReprogPeriod == "0"){

            wrData = "fromDate" + STSEP2 +                  
                        "workOrder" + STSEP2 +
                        "worker" + STSEP2 +
                        scr.getValue("TBFromDate") + STSEP2 +                 
                        workerWOReprogram.getRSWorkOrderValue() + STSEP2 +               
                        workerWOReprogram.getRSWorkerValue() + STSEP2 +   
                        "1";            
        }
        else{

            "fromDate|workOrder|

            wrData = scr.getValue("TBFromDate") + STSEP2 +                  
                        scr.getValue("RSWorkOrder" + STSEP2 +
                        scr.getValue("RSWorker" + STSEP2 +
                        scr.getValue("TBFromDate") + STSEP2 +                            
                        workerWOReprogram.getRSWorkerValue() + STSEP2 +   
                        "1";            
        }
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: O problema deverá estar quando faz `processParam.Split` não lhe retorna um *array* com dois índices mas apenas um, então quando tenta aceder ao 2º índice (posição **1** do *array*) dá erro. Tem que colocar mais informação na sua questão. O que é o separador `GV.stSep`? De onde vem? Qual a ligação entre o JS e o C#?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Foi isso mesmo, obrigado por ajudar !!! Não vou responder as suas perguntas pois achei o erro com base na sua dica, tamo junto!